# How to extract the number from file link and convert it date

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have one column name "**link**" having a data like:-

```
 Link
www_dump/e3_upoad/sdf/smc_sm_lys_vu_12221126-509
www_dump/e3_upoad/sdi/smc_sm_lys_vu_11342356-43445
```

The Output I want to extract the number and convert it to
It is something like this

```
Link                                                 DATE
www_dump/e3_upoad/sdf/smc_sm_lys_vu_12221126-509  12221126
www_dump/e3_upoad/sdi/smc_sm_lys_vu_11342356-43445  11342356 
and convert it to date format.
```

I tried using substr but no luck

Comment: Is 12221126 a date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use REGEXP_SUBSTR to parse the text:

```
select link, TO_DATE( regexp_substr(link,'.*smc_sm_lys_vu_(\\d*)-.*',1,1,'e'), 'YYYYMMDD') "DATE"
from values 
('www_dump/e3_upoad/sdf/smc_sm_lys_vu_20220916-509'),
('www_dump/e3_upoad/sdi/smc_sm_lys_vu_20210801-43445') tmp(link);

+----------------------------------------------------+------------+
|                        LINK                        |    DATE    |
+----------------------------------------------------+------------+
| www_dump/e3_upoad/sdf/smc_sm_lys_vu_20220916-509   | 2022-09-16 |
| www_dump/e3_upoad/sdi/smc_sm_lys_vu_20210801-43445 | 2021-08-01 |
+----------------------------------------------------+------------+
```